# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_iter'. Is this a problem with the way I installed scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn import datasets 
import numpy as np

# Assigning the petal length and petal width of the 150 flower samples to Matrix X 
# Class labels of the flower to vector y

iris = datasets.load_iris() 
X = iris.data[:, [2, 3]] 
y = iris.target
print('Class labels:', np.unique(y))

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1, stratify=y)

print('Labels counts in y:', np.bincount(y)) 
print('Labels counts in y_train:', np.bincount(y_train)) 
print ('Labels counts in y_test:', np.bincount(y_test))

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 
sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit(X_train) 
X_train_std = sc.transform(X_train) 
X_test_std = sc.transform(X_test)

from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron

ppn = Perceptron(n_iter=40, eta0=0.1, random_state=1)
ppn.fit(X_train_std, y_train)

y_pred = ppn.predict(X_test_std) 
print('Misclassified samples: %d' % (y_test != y_pred).sum())
```

When I run I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Desfios 5/Desktop/Python/Ch3.py", line 27, in <module>
    ppn = Perceptron(n_iter=40, eta0=0.1, random_state=1)
  File "C:\Users\Desfios 5\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 72, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_iter'
```

I've tried uninstalling and installing scikit-learn but that did not help. Any help?

Comment: Are you sure that `n_iter` is supposed to be given as a parameter to `Perceptron()` and not to `ppn.fit()`?

Comment: Please consult the sklearn documentation.  `Perceptron` instantiation has no such parameter.  The class *does* have an attribute `n_iter`, but there is no `__init__` parameter by that name.

Answer (score 6):

I just change the `n_iter` to `max_iter` and it work for me

`ppn = Perceptron(max_iter=40, eta0=0.3, random_state=0)`

Answer (score 1):

You receive this error

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_iter'

because the Perceptron has no parameter 'n_iter' you can use before fitting it.

You are trying to access the `n_iter_` attribute, which is an "Estimated attribute" (you can tell by the underscore at the end) and only stored after the fit method has been called. [Reference in Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#estimated-attributes)

Before fitting, you can only access the `n_iter_no_change` parameter for `n_iter`.

Answer (score 0):

for skimage version 0.21.0 it is changed to max_num_iter=100. It worked or me